# Rewriting rules 302 for K2 component?

Tags: regex, joomla, url-rewriting

I'm moving a component and its content from a domain to another...
While I'm doing this operation I would like a 302 redirect for all content of this component to a "Under construction" page.
I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php\?option=com_k2&(.*)/?$ /under-construction/ [L,R=302]
```

and also this one:

```
RewriteRule /index\.php\?option=com_k2&([^/]*) /under-construction/ [L,R=302]
```

With some variations between both. But I can't find any solution working, I'm always getting a 404.

Comment: What was the input and what will be your desired output?

Comment: Thanks @GowthamShiva. Actually I solved it by installing REDJ component which allow me to write 302 redirect with regex. So it give now n the component : From URL "/index.php\?option=com_k2" and to URL "{scheme}://{siteurl}/notre-site-en-travaux". Works great...